# How to use OnClickListener Method in AppWidgetProvider class

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to perform more operations when widget is clicked, with this code the onclick action only opens an activity, is it possible to add a onClickListener where I can add more code and operations like in Activities to run before activities opening?
 Here is my Code.

```
public class WidgetActivity extends AppWidgetProvider{

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];


        Intent int1=new Intent();
        int1.setClass(context, Splash.class);

        PendingIntent pend1=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, int1, 0);

        RemoteViews view1=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_main_1);

        view1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.repClear, pend1);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view1);

        }
}
```

}

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

i want to do that when i claick on icon on image 1 then 6 round circle around the icon onClick as in image2 . please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to perform more operations when widget is clicked, with this
>   code the onclick action only opens an activity, is it possible to add
>   a onClickListener where I can add more code and operations like in
>   Activities to run before activities opening?

In your actual scenario you are calling Activity when you click on element. If you want to perform more different operations you have to invoke Broadcast instead of Activity:

```
// calling Intent on your widget
Intent i = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);           
i.setAction("your.intent.filter.action.name"); // assign intent action
int flag = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, flag);
view1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.repClear, pi);
```

Then you need to implement `onReceive()` method in your widget:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("your.intent.filter.action.name")) {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Similar for other PendingIntents.

### Update:

Example how to update widget (you can call it explicitly from almost everywhere):

```
public static void updateWidget(Context c, boolean hide) {
    AppWidgetManager am = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(c, WidgetActivity.class);  
    int[] allWidgetIds = am.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    for (int widgetId: allWidgetIds) {  
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), layout);

        if (!hide) {
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(viewId, View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(viewId, View.INVISIBLE); // OR GONE
        }

        // finally calling request for update of widget
        am.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

**Calling:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals("your.intent.filter.action.name")) {
       updateWidget(context, false);
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equals("your.another.intent.filter.action.name")) {
       updateWidget(context, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: can i do this  ?

'public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     super.onReceive(context, intent);
     if (intent.getAction().equals("your.intent.filter.action.name")) {
        // do your stuff
      ImageButton img=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      ImageButton img1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
      img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
 }'

Comment: If images are in widget layout (remoteView) you can do it but you need to perform update of widget so create for example static method and make update of widget (similar as in your `onUpdate()` method)

Comment: all things are available in layout. but i don't how i handle it. If you provide me some code then i will be very thankful of you .please sir

Comment: @Gauravkumar did you read all what i wrote for your? :) In onReceive() method you need to call it. Answer updated. Check it out.

Comment: @Gauravkumar welcome. So if it works, can you accept answer as working one?

Comment: @Gauravkumar you are doing something wrong. Code works because is copied from my project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40365/discussion-between-gaurav-kumar-and-sajmon)